# Whats wrong with my code? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

This is the code I wrote,

```
// Dear modders: I dont recomend that you edit this part but what do I know? Im just the creator of the game
var Name=prompt("What is your name?");
var Class=prompt("What is your class? No Class, Ranger, Recon, Engineer, Soldier, Spy, Agent, Knight");
// This is how the stats are set
Stats=confirm("What are your stats? (You have 20 points to use)");
var BaseSTstat=prompt("What is your streagth stat?");
var BaseDXstat=prompt("What is your dexterity stat?");
var BaseCHstat=prompt("What is your chrisma stat?");
var BaseHTstat=prompt("What is your health stat?");
var BaseINstat=prompt("What is your intlegniince stat?");
var BaseWSstat=prompt("What is your wisdom stat?");
// This is how it checks if the ammont of stat points you have are under 20
// After here I get errors
If (BaseSTstat + BaseDXstat + BaseCHstat + BaseHTstat + BaseINstat + BaseWSstat > 20);{
    confirm("Too many points, try again");
}
// This is how skills are set
Skills=confirm("What are your skills? (You may add 10 points to any skills)");
CombatSkills=confirm("What are your combat skills?");
var  BaseRIskill=prompt("How good are you with rilfes?");
var  BasePIskill=prompt("How good are you with pistols?");
var  BaseHEskill=prompt("How good are you with heavy wepons?");
var  BaseLRskill=prompt("How good are you with long-ranged wepons?");
var  BaseFIskill=prompt("How good are you with your fists?");
var  BaseMEskill=prompt("How good are you with melee wepons?");
ActiveSkills=confirm("What are your active skills?");
var  BaseENskill=prompt("How good are you at engeerings?");
var  BaseCOskill=prompt("How good are you at computers?");
var  BaseLPskill=prompt("How good are you at lock picking?");
PassiveSkills=confirm("What are you passive skills?");
var BaseACskill=prompt("How good is your accuacy");
var BaseDOskill=prompt("How good are you at dodgeing?");
// add the sneaking skill to all the class IF commands
var BaseSNskill=prompt("How good are you at sneaking?");
// add a check for if the player added too many skill points
// Right here I get an error as well VVV
if (BaseRIskill + BasePIskill + BaseHEskill + BaseLRskill + BaseFIskill + BaseMEskill BaseENskill + BaseCOskill + BaseLPskill + BaseACskill + BaseDOskill > 10);{
    confirm("too many points, try again");
}
// This is how skill and stat values are redone as per classes
If (Class="No Class");{
    STstat = BaseSTstat;
    DXstat = BaseDXstat;
    CHstat = BaseCHstat;
    HTstat = BaseHTstat;
    INstat = BaseINstat;
    WSstat = BaseWSstat;
    RIskill = BaseRIskill;
    PIskill = BasePIskill;
    HEskill = BaseHEskill;
    LRskill = BaseLRskill;
    FIskill = BaseFIskill;
    MEskill = BaseMEskill;
    ENskill = BaseENskill;
    COskill = BaseCOskill;
    LPskill = BaseLPskill;
    ACskill = BaseACskill;
    DOskill = BaseDOskill;
}
If (Class="Ranger");{
    STstat = 1 + BaseSTstat;
    DXstat = BaseDXstat;
    CHstat = BaseCHstat;
    HTstat = BaseHTstat;
    INstat = BaseINstat;
    WSstat = BaseWSstat;
    RIskill = BaseRIskill;
    PIskill = BasePIskill;
    HEskill = BaseHEskill;
    LRskill = 1 + BaseLRskill;
    FIskill = BaseFIskill;
    MEskill = BaseMEskill;
    ENskill = BaseENskill;
    COskill = BaseCOskil - 2;
    LPskill = BaseLPskill;
    ACskill = BaseACskill;
    DOskill = BaseDOskill;
}
If (Class="Recon");{
    HTstat = 1 + BaseHTstat;
    PIskill = 1 + BasePIskill;
    STstat = BaseSTstat - 1;
    HEskill = BaseHEskill - 1;
    DXstat = BaseDXstat;
    CHstat = BaseCHstat;
    INstat = BaseINstat;
    WSstat = BaseWSstat;
    RIskill = BaseRIskill;
    LRskill = BaseLRskill;
    FIskill = BaseFIskill;
    MEskill = BaseMEskill;
    ENskill = BaseENskill;
    COskill = BaseCOskill;
    LPskill = BaseLPskill;
    ACskill = BaseACskill;
    DOskill = BaseDOskill;
}
If (Class="Engineer");{
    STstat = BaseSTstat;
    DXstat = BaseDXstat;
    CHstat = BaseCHstat;
    HTstat = BaseHTstat;
    INstat = BaseINstat;
    WSstat = BaseWSstat;
    RIskill = BaseRIskill;
    PIskill = BasePIskill;
    HEskill = BaseHEskill - 2;
    LRskill = BaseLRskill;
    FIskill = BaseFIskill;
    MEskill = BaseMEskill;
    ENskill = 1 + BaseENskill;
    COskill = 1 + BaseCOskill;
    LPskill = BaseLPskill;
    ACskill = BaseACskill;
    DOskill = BaseDOskill;
}
If (Class="Soldier");{
    STstat = BaseSTstat;
    DXstat = BaseDXstat;
    CHstat = BaseCHstat;
    HTstat = BaseHTstat;
    INstat = BaseINstat;
    WSstat = BaseWSstat;
    RIskill = 1 + BaseRIskill;
    PIskill = BasePIskill;
    HEskill = BaseHEskill;
    LRskill = BaseLRskill;
    FIskill = BaseFIskill;
    MEskill = BaseMEskill;
    ENskill = BaseENskill - 1;
    COskill = BaseCOskill - 1;
    LPskill = BaseLPskill;
    ACskill = 1 + BaseACskill;
    DOskill = BaseDOskill;
}
If (Class="Spy");{
    STstat = BaseSTstat;
    DXstat = BaseDXstat;
    CHstat = BaseCHstat;
    HTstat = BaseHTstat;
    INstat = BaseINstat;
    WSstat = BaseWSstat;
    RIskill = BaseRIskill - 1;
    PIskill = 1 + BasePIskill;
    HEskill = BaseHEskill - 1;
    LRskill = BaseLRskill;
    FIskill = BaseFIskill;
    MEskill = BaseMEskill;
    ENskill = BaseENskill;
    COskill = BaseCOskill;
    LPskill = 1 + BaseLPskill;
    ACskill = BaseACskill;
    DOskill = BaseDOskill;
}
If (Class="Agent");{
    STstat = BaseSTstat;
    DXstat = BaseDXstat;
    CHstat = BaseCHstat;
    HTstat = BaseHTstat;
    INstat = BaseINstat;
    WSstat = BaseWSstat;
    RIskill = BaseRIskill - 1;
    PIskill = 1 + BasePIskill;
    HEskill = BaseHEskill - 1;
    LRskill = BaseLRskill;
    FIskill = BaseFIskill;
    MEskill = BaseMEskill;
    ENskill = BaseENskill;
    COskill = 1 + BaseCOskill;
    LPskill = BaseLPskill;
    ACskill = BaseACskill;
    DOskill = BaseDOskill;
}
If (Class="Knight");{
    STstat = 1 + BaseSTstat;
    DXstat = BaseDXstat;
    CHstat = BaseCHstat - 1;
    HTstat = BaseHTstat;
    INstat = BaseINstat;
    WSstat = BaseWSstat;
    RIskill = BaseRIskill;
    PIskill = BasePIskill;
    HEskill = BaseHEskill;
    LRskill = BaseLRskill;
    FIskill = BaseFIskill;
    MEskill = 1 + BaseMEskill;
    ENskill = BaseENskill;
    COskill = BaseCOskill;
    LPskill = BaseLPskill;
    ACskill = BaseACskill;
    DOskill = BaseDOskill - 1;
}
confirm("Is this how you want you charitor to be?");
```

This is the code I have, After setting the stat points I get an "Invalid Javascript error"
Can someone tell me whats wrong with the code? I only have basic JavaScript knowledge and as far as I know it should work.

Comment: Having a `;` direct after an `if(...)` will esscially cut it off. It would be like doing: `if(...){ }`.

Comment: in addition to @SpencerWieczorek comment; `=` assigns a value, use `==` to check for equality

Comment: "What's wrong with my code" is a horrible title. Change it to something which actually indicates the problem.

Comment: All those variables e.g `BaseSTstat` are strings. You can't add them together and then find out if they're greater than 10.

Answer (score 2):

Update your code from

```
If (BaseSTstat + BaseDXstat + BaseCHstat + BaseHTstat + BaseINstat + BaseWSstat > 20);{
confirm("Too many points, try again");
}
```

to

```
if (BaseSTstat + BaseDXstat + BaseCHstat + BaseHTstat + BaseINstat + BaseWSstat > 20){
confirm("Too many points, try again");
}
```

**Errors**

1. if should be in lowercase
2. there should be no semicolon after if condition

Additionally, in other parts of the code there is an error as pointed by my fellow friend Spencer Wieczorek,

3. Use `==` (or `===`) for comparison, not `=` which is assignment.

Comment: 3. Use `==` (or `===`) for comparison, not `=` which is assignment.

Answer (score 2):

First thing that pops out is the `semicolon` between `)` and `{` in your `if` statements.

A `if` statement should look like this:

```
if (1 == 1) {

}
```

And not

```
if (1 == 1); {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throughout the code you are using `If` instead of `if`. Javascript is case sensetive.

You have semicolons (`;`) that separates the `if` statements and the code that it is supposed to control.

In comparisons you have used the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the equality comparison operator (`==`).

So code like this:

```
If (Class="No Class");{
```

should be:

```
if (Class == "No Class") {
```

The syntax error that you get is because you are missing a `+` between `BaseMEskill` and `BaseENskill`.